# La différence entre « il y a quelques lunes » et « il y a de cela quelques lunes »

Tags: expressions

> Cette question, on me l’a posée, il y a **de cela** quelques lunes.

D'habitude, on dit par ellipse « il y a quelques lunes ». Je pense que « de cela » signifie « depuis qu'une chose est survenue », mais je me demande à quoi cela sert d'y ajouter « de cela », aussi superflu que cela puisse paraître ?

Ces deux expressions reviennent-elles au même ?

Comment: Je viens de trouver un article que je n'ai pas encore lu : http://la-grammaire-de-forator.over-blog.fr/article-il-y-a-et-il-y-a-de-cela-79372630.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comme tu le fais remarquer toi-même « il y a quelques lunes » est une ellipse, les deux phrases sont strictement équivalentes.

Ça fonctionne dans tous les cas : « il y a de cela quelques jours », etc…

Je dirais que la forme avec « de cela » est en quelque sorte plus soutenue.